# How do I read Minecraft packets?

Tags: minecraft, packet

I'm not familiar with packets and trying to make my own implementation of Minecraft server.
I used `net.createServer()` and the incoming data looks like this

```
�     localhostc�
�0�H��name����=�0�"0
��]�
�ܩ X�Ox��R��Y������[�@��)Ҡ��
����{�h���k��>#A�"Qv�� ����]��;�7HA��>�t�����bإ7~T.�>[����jÅ(�� �+ӂ7˟nɟ(�=gé��P�¿û�ª�øþ¥¿´��¨ò͵¯��±Ö��¦Ì��Ç�®Á�ð�Ú�݃��¡ÄÜ«Ë��»�úÛ��º��èã��ۿî�æ�ø��Î�ðê�Á؍¦çÄ�������
"��)�q웇x*z^�N�Y�i`_��F`��:�H�x���d��5Z(�����1VE
ܖ$tC6QH]��P���:���Q���y�`��AF��}89�U���7R���R�`��#g�ʉ�d})�w�&��&c��,Y?e���H5wF�:�Q��8�2���NG��o��4�@��G�"^ֵ���Os�Hpg�L�S���gS=&"IK
/B�3���i��(�i�p�T�ΣaQ!r{�"Hqr^�;�
����KE~�|6�v�)̒3��EL��,A�<%�
�����6c�LU�NE5�4j^O���
�xZL���o&�nL�G�--I������
��O�
ht,�
C��z� �[�:�ew�w0N$�$\N�B���iS����j�\i@���Q��0S�"�lL\�4��b;�������<A��0ni�=�A��n��a�N�
```

How do I read this and convert to JSON?

My code

```
import { createServer } from "net"

const server = createServer()

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected")
  })

  socket.on("data", (packet) => {
    console.log(packet.toString())
  })
})

server.listen(25565, () => {
  console.log("Listening")
})
```

I'm trying to make this with minimal dependencies, so I searched about this a lot but I could not find how to do this.

Comment: You might want to read about the Minecraft Protocol first, e.g. [here](https://wiki.vg/Protocol).

Comment: I read about it and couldn't find how to read the packets at there.

Comment: As you can see from the data you posted, a packet is not encoded in plain text or JSON, it is a specific format. You basically need to read the data byte by byte and translate this (according to the specification from the previous link) to something your program can work with. If you are not familiar with the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and how TCP communication works, I recommend checking out existing open source Minecraft server implementations (like [Glowstone](https://github.com/GlowstoneMC/Glowstone)) first.